# Hidden characters in integer-like string

Tags: python, pandas

I **scraped** data about fundraising from the web and put it into a table.

As I start to clean the data , I see that some elements, for instance "2 000000", are read "2\xa0000000" by the machine.

1/ What does that mean ?

2/ How can I remove it ? (as I want to transform the whole column to integers)

Best,

Comment: It's an escape sequence, here, for a non-breaking space. You probably want to replace all whitespace with empty strings and then re-parse. Or, if it's systematic, pass `\xa` to `read_csv`'s `thousands` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix a `DataFrame` column, use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('\D', '').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have escape sequences read in as Unicode characters in the string. The easiest way to remove those characters without using replace on each specific showing is using the `unicodedata` package.

Specifically:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

string1 = "2\xa0000000"

new_string = normalize('NFKD', string1)

print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
2 000000
```

This package was already built into my machine, but you may need to install it if you used a different method to build your python package than I. I find this better because this normalization works across a lot of various formatting, so you do not need to use replace each time you see something else that is not formatted correctly. It's an escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

Character of hex code `A0` is non-breaking space. So to speak, you can just treat it as a space in most cases. According to my experience, it mostly come up when I process some data generated from Microsoft Office products, or from the web when people put the HTML code `&nbsp;` on it.

Unfortunately, python `split()` (for example, I don't know how you process your data) will not treat that as space. But as it is just a distinct character, you can solve the issue with:

```
longstring.replace('\xA0', ' ').split()
```

PS: Read again your question, seems it should be ignored to produce the number two million as an data entity. So you might want to replace `'\xA0'` with empty string.